# How can I save the context for a graphical widget though AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am doing one POC on AngularJS.

Use Case Scenario is

1) Widget has graphical representation of data.
2) Now, I want to save the context for the graphical widget.

I am not sure , how can I save the context for a graphical widget through AngularJS?

Any help and suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: context means you want to save data used for graph?

Comment: if yes then you can use angular scope.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I have a widget, which has the graphical representation of data. Now, user wants to highlight some part of the graph and send to another widget. Now, few questions,1) How user can highlight which user wants in the graph? 2) How can I get the pixels which user wants to highlight 3) How can I store that and send to another widget?

Comment: Below are the answer for your questions.
1) You can provide a checkbox or something like, i don't know what is your actual requirement.But if it's a check box you can set style to that dom element using directive of angular
2)I didnt get you on this much,i believe you want to highlight the point where user click.There are multiple ways to do it.like directive or in service level. 
3)There are multiple ways in angular to send data from one scope to other.
if it is in different scope then you can use $broadcast and $emit as per hierarchy.
and if its in same scope you can use $watch functionality

Comment: Hi Pankaj, Thanks for your reply. I am using HightChart to meet my requirement. Now, Can you please tell me , How I can refer my custom highchart script from angularJS. Thanks, Soum.

Comment: it is so simple..write one directive..in that bind you hightchart function to element parameter.it will  look like element.highchart(function(){
//code here
});
you can also pass your scope variables into it to configure highchart.